# Split an array according to user defined rules

Tags: python, arrays, for-loop

I am new to Python and I am quite struggling with how to split the array according to user-defined rules.
Say I have an array with elements inside:

A=[0,1,2,6,7,8,9,14,15,16]

I want to use python to split the above array into several groups.
So if the interval between the current element and the next element is smaller than 2, then they belong to one group, else belong to a different group.

So essentially I want my new array to look like this:

B = [[0,1,2] [6,7,8,9] [14,15,16]]

I was thinking to use for loop and loop through array A, but not quite sure how to do so....

Comment: Is there any attempt you have tried?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A basic for loop works

```
a=[0,1,2,6,7,8,9,14,15,16]

g = []
tmp = [] 
for i in range(len(a)):
   tmp.append(a[i])
   if i==len(a)-1 or a[i+1] - a[i] >= 2:
      g.append(tmp)
      tmp = []

print(g)
```

Output

```
[[0, 1, 2], [6, 7, 8, 9], [14, 15, 16]]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just iterate over your `A` list, starting a new sub-list in `B` each time the difference between the current value in `A` and the previous one is more than 1:

```
A=[0,1,2,6,7,8,9,14,15,16]

B = [[A[0]]]
Bindex = 0
last = A[0]
for i in range(1, len(A)):
    if A[i] - last >= 2:
        B.append([A[i]])
        Bindex += 1
    else:
        B[Bindex].append(A[i])
    last = A[i]

print(B)
```

Output:

```
[[0, 1, 2], [6, 7, 8, 9], [14, 15, 16]]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
A = [0, 1, 2, 6, 7, 8, 9, 14, 15, 17]

temp = []
B = []
for index, value in enumerate(A):
    if index != 0 and value - A[index-1] >= 2:
        B.append(temp)
        temp = [value]
        continue
    temp.append(value)
B.append(temp)
```

How the code works:

- Enumerate takes a list and makes it into tuple format.
  So enumerate will make your list look like this:
  (0, 0) (1, 1) (2, 2) (3, 6) (4, 7) etc....
- `index != 0` condition ensures that you do not do access an element before 0 in the next part of the if statement. I.e. `A[index-1]`, if index was 0 then this would be `A[0-1] = A[-1] = NOT what we want` (because this will give the last element)
- `temp = [value]` makes a new list. I.e. the next list to be appended into B.
- `continue` goes back to the for loop skipping any code below it for that particular iteration.

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding _why_ and/or _how_ this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Comment: @Swier Thanks. Good point. I have added a explanation now.

Answer (score 0):

I think an elegant and much faster way is to use `itertools.groupby` like:

```
from itertools import groupby
from operator import itemgetter

A=[0,1,2,6,7,8,9,14,15,16]
B = [list(map(itemgetter(1), group)) for key, group in groupby(enumerate(A), lambda x: x[0] - x[1])]
```

Comment: This is good for the specific example mentioned, but if the condition changed to be that the interval needed to be `3` to start a new group, it wouldn't work.

Answer (score 0):

```
A = [0, 1, 2, 6, 7, 8, 9, 14, 15, 17]

B = []
start = 0
end = 0
for i, val in enumerate(A):
    if i != 0 and val - A[i-1] >= 2:
        B.append(A[start:end])
        start = end
    end += 1
B.append(A[start:end])
```